# how to send xml from one site to another using post method?

Tags: xml

I am new in xml and trying to send xml as a post method using form.This form will be submitting to another website (that is on asp) which return the correspond result.
If anyone knows how to do this plz guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

Insert a hidden element in the form
 Set the form method to "POST"
 ON form submit, form the required XML and set the hidden input value to XML string
 Access the xml from ASP page using the hidden element name

```
        <form id="xmlForm" method="POST" action="xxx.asp" onsubmit="return appendXML(this)">
        <input type="hidden" id="xml" name="xml"/> 
        .....
    </form>

    function appendXML(Obj){
        var xml="<xml>...</xml>";
        $(Obj).find("input#xml").val(xml);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I was also doing the same thing but when i set variable (var) and add xml it generates an error.

Comment: I think there will be some special characters. If so, use "\" before the characters like "<,>,',"... Also please post the error message you get